# Как синтаксически разобрать поговорки?

Tags: синтаксис

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как синтаксически разобрать поговорки: "Нет лучше дружка чем родная матушка", "Жизнь дана на добрые дела".

Comment: А Вы запятые в школе проходили?

Answer (score 1):

Оба предложения повествовательные, невосклицательные. 1 предложение простое,односоставное (основа"нет"), безличное,распространенное, осложнено сравнительным оборотом, перед союзом "чем" надо поставить запятую.
2 предложение простое, двусоставное (основа "жизнь дана"), распространенное, не осложнено.

Образцы предложений [здесь](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200304703)

**Я есть**. **Нет** меня. Выделены основы.

Comment: В первом предложении основа - "нет дружка"

Comment: Ларf, Виктор1799, здравствуйте! Почему Вам не нравится основа НЕТ ЛУЧШЕ? Здесь ведь важно не то, что дружка НЕТ, а то, что его НЕТ ЛУЧШЕ. Жду ответа.

Comment: Уважаемая Катя! Мне кажется, "лучше" - это несогласованное определение. "Нет дружка КАКОГО? лучше"

Comment: И я так рассуждала сначала. Потом появились сомнения. В предложении типа НЕТ ТЕБЯ КРАШЕ сказуемое (главный член) НЕТ КРАШЕ. Так ведь? Спорьте, жду.

Comment: Кстати, по поводу включения сравнительного оборота в состав сказуемого я тоже думал, но немного иначе, чем Вы. Я допускал сказуемое в виде "нет дружка, чем матушка", где "чем" синонимично"как", но потом пришел к выводу, что "чем матушка" - это несогласованное определение (нет дружка КАКОГО? чем (как) матушка

Comment: Добрый вечер! Сравнительная степень прилагательного может быть несогласованным определением! (Посмотрите, например, тему "Обособление несогласованных определений). Почему нужно включать "Дружка" в основу - не понимаю. Слово НЕТ является основой безличного предложения. Вот нашла для Вас предложения с выделенной основой. Посмотрите. Ссылку в комментарий вставлять не умею, добавлю в ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Уважаемая Катя! Извините за долгое молчание: был занят срочными делами. Насчет "нет тебя краше" Вы, по-моему правы. Нет краше - сказуемое. Но ведь это совсем другая конструкция, нежели поставленная в вопросе. "Нет тебя на улице" - здесь уже сказуемое - "нет тебя". В вопросе "Нет лучше дружка..." основная мысль - нет дружка. Далее. Какого дружка? Лучше, то есть лучшего. Что касается сравнительной степени прилагательного, то они действительно могут выступать в роли сказуемых (Эта книга интереснее), но могут быть и несогласованными определениями при существительном (Дайте мне книгу поинтереснее)

Спасибо, Лариса! С интересом прочитал о слове "нет" у Шапиро. Но у меня есть старый и уважамый мною учебник для поступающих на гуманитарные факультеты (авторы Л.А.Шевченко,Н.М.Пипченко). Цитирую: "Безличные предложения образуются из сочетания глагола БЫЛ, БУДУ с отрицанием НЕ и родительного падежа существительного, отрицательного слова НЕТ и род.п. существительного: ГЕРАСИМА уже НЕ БЫЛО на дворе. У меня НЕТ ОТЦА. 
  Здесь разнобой с тем, что пишет Шапиро, но мне кажется, что Шевченко, Пипченко правы, ведь граматическая основа предложения называется основой и потому, что в ней заключено зерно смысла предложения. "НЕТ" почти ни о чем не говорит, а вот "Нет отца" заключает в себе основную мысль предложения.

Благодарю, Лариса! Ваш комментарий вновь доказывает, что язык настолько живой организм, что его бывает очень трудно втиснуть в рамки каких-то схем

Comment: Я думаю, здесь снова смешение формального (структурного, традиционного) синтаксиса и семантического. И тридцать лет назад мы выделяли основу "НЕТ". С точки зрения семантики мы и в предложении "Мне не спится" должны выделить подлежащее, ведь это Я не сплю. А с точки зрения формального синтаксиса только сказуемое.

Comment: Большое спасибо за примеры со ср.ст. в качестве определения.